# connect to server phpmyadmin database from local in wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I want to connect my local Wordpress database to cpanel database server phpmyadmin.

this is my wp-config file configs

```
   define( 'DB_NAME', 'pixelshop' );

   /** MySQL database username */
   define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

   /** MySQL database password */
   define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );

   /** MySQL hostname */
   define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );

   /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
   define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4' );

   /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
   define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

Comment: You can't. Cpanel's phpMyAdmin can only access local databases, and your localhost server is external in cpanel's point of view. Install phpMyAdmin locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to connect local and online banks. You can connect a local WP to an online bank only when a Hosting makes this available, but you should check with your hosting provider if this option is enabled.